# Initialize UserForm multiple times

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, userform

For a project I am working on I am programming a UserForm to fill in an Excel file by asking certain data to the person that will use the sheet. There is data needed for multiple sets which ask for the same sort of data. Therefore I want one UserForm to pop up multiple times to fill in data at different places in the Excel file. A short step-by-step guide on what I want the program to do is the following:

1. Ask for the amount of data sets (*i*).
2. Copy the preset Excel cells from set 1 and paste them underneath each other until they reach *i* sets.
3. Ask the user for the data to be filled in in set 1, then let the UserForm fill it in the cells in set 1.
4. Repeat step 3 for each data set until set *i* is filled in, then unload the UserForm.

Steps 1 and 2 are no problem, but what I have after those steps is the following code. I would like to have a way to initialize the UserForm for every value of *i*, which probably should be included in the For-loop, before it goes to the next value of *i*. It should be the same UserForm every time since the data required for each set consists of the same things, just other values.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

For i = 1 To Sheet4.Cells(5, 4)
    If Sheet4.Cells(5, 4) = 1 Or i = 1 Then
        LastCrossing = "Crossing"
    Else
        LastCrossing = "Crossing " & i
    End If

    Set CrossingLoc = Sheet4.Cells.Find(What:=LastCrossing, After:=Sheet4.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    CaptString = i
    UserForm10.Caption = "Crossing " & CaptString
    CrossingLoc = CrossingLoc.Row + 3

    If Sheet4.Cells(CrossingLoc, 4) = "" Then
        i = Sheet4.Cells(5, 4)
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Is it possible to load the UserForm multiple times for each set from 1 to *i*? And if so, could you explain me how I do this?

Maybe a solution is to load a new UserForm every time at the end of the UserForm until set *i* has been filled in?

P.S. A lot of the code I have to work with is from someone else whose contact details I don't have.

Comment: i think this is approach wouldn't be the best possible - depending on your **i** you might end up with lots of user forms open. Just create the UserForm and make some forward/backwards buttons and switch between the data.

Comment: Hi therak, thanks for your view on this problem! I will try a workaround with the forward and backward buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do this by creating a loop on one UserForm where the user is asked to fill in the amount `i`. Then in this loop the next UserForm is run in which all data for set `i` is asked. Filling that in and clicking the `CommandButton` then takes you back in this loop to the next value of `i`.

This way the caption as coded in the question changes as well.

```
If i = 1 Then
    Selection.Replace What:="Crossing*", Replacement:="Crossing " & i, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select
    Range("E4").Value = 1
    UserForm13.Show
    End If
ElseIf i > 1 Then
'   Fill in 01
    Range("E4").Value = 1
    UserForm13.Show
End If
'   Fill in Pipes 02 - i
    For i = 2 To TextBox1.Value
    CrossingLoc.Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(3, 0).PasteSpecial
    Selection.Replace What:="Crossing*", Replacement:="Crossing " & i, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
    Range("E4").Value = i
    UserForm13.Show 'The UserForm that has to be repeated.
End If
Next i
```

This might not be award-winning coding, but it does the trick.